# When click searchbar it the value below come up

Tags: java, android, image, listview, searchbar

[its image showing value and search bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hxq9r.jpg)

[it is the image showing when clicking the search bar it will come up the values in list-view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ao1l8.jpg)

I want to know why this happen and how to avoid the situation please help me thanks in advance

```
public class ListItem extends AppCompatActivity
{
    ListView listView1;
    ArrayList<String> listproduct;
    ArrayAdapter<String > adapternew;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.listitem);
        ActionBar actionBar=getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setTitle("Please Select the Item");
      SearchView search=(SearchView)findViewById(R.id.Search);
        ScrollView scroll=(ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.Scroll);
        ListView listView1=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.Listview);
        listproduct=new ArrayList<>();
        listproduct.add("Stove Top Stuffing");
        listproduct.add("Campell's Soup");
        listproduct.add("Tide");
        listproduct.add("Pampers");
        listproduct.add("Pepsi Products");
        listproduct.add("Tang");
        listproduct.add("Top Ramen");
        listproduct.add("Knorr");
        listproduct.add("Palmolive");
        listproduct.add("Scotch-Brite");
        listproduct.add("Bounty Paper Towls");
        listproduct.add("Oreo Cookies");
        listproduct.add("Quaker Oats");
        listproduct.add("Lays Potato Chips");
        adapternew = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,listproduct);
        listView1.setAdapter(adapternew);
        SearchManager manager=(SearchManager)getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        search.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                search.clearFocus();
            if(listproduct.contains(query))
            {
            adapternew.getFilter().filter(query);
            }
                return false;
            }
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                adapternew.getFilter().filter(newText);
                return false;
            }
             });
          listView1.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int newposition, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(ListItem.this,listproduct.get(newposition)+"",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent i=new Intent(ListItem.this,AddOrder.class);
                i.putExtra("position",listproduct.get(newposition));
                //adapternew.notifyDataSetChanged();
                 startActivity(i);
            }
        });



    }
}
```

here is the code that is to show the list view item and i want to know whether the value in list view come up when clicking the search bar

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <SearchView
        android:id="@+id/Search"

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:iconifiedByDefault="false"
        android:queryHint="Search Here"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.00" />


    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/Scroll"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="-8dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="396dp">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="5dp"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="9dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="2dp" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/Listview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/Search"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.100"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.200">

    </ListView>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

and this is the xml file of the listview

Comment: search operation are also working fine

Comment: why are you using scrollview ?

Comment: yes code posted

Comment: i used it to view all the item i am new to android so i take that there is any other option to do that

Comment: See my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is the code you are wanting.

No need to use `scrollview` here because `ListView` itself is scrollable. LinearLayout with Vertical Orientation will solve your issue

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="5dp"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="9dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="2dp" />


<SearchView
    android:id="@+id/Search"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="56dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:iconifiedByDefault="false"
    android:queryHint="Search Here"/>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/Listview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

</ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: i removed the Scroll view and I changed the layout to constraint layout to Linear layout .it work 100% .thumbs up for your reply...

Answer (score 1):

I think with `ConstraintLayout` , you can use `app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf` to assign it below the desired view instead of `layout_below`

```
<ListView
        android:id="@+id/Listview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.100"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/search" <!-- change here -->
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.200">
```

Comment: Yeah, you are right but do you know why she is using ScrollView?

Comment: I removed the scroll view